# Can you catch errors in QML declaritive code?

Tags: qt, error-handling, qml, declarative

I have a (declarative) line in my QML file which is logging an error and I want to catch it and log certain variables to try and figure out what's going on. The line is something like (contained in a `Repeater` hence the use of `index`):

```
a: ((n === -1) || (n - p > 7) || (index >= t)) ? "" : b[p+index].c
```

(no, those aren't my *actual* variable names, I've renamed them to prevent information leakage - the actual names are not important).

When running the code, I am occasionally getting the error:

```
file:///path/to/SomeFile.qml:7: TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined
```

leading me to believe that one of those variables is wrong somehow when the `a` field is being modified based on the other variables.

I am aware of `try/catch` in *procudural* QML code but I'm not sure how to do something similar for declarative code (or even if it's possible).

Is there a way to catch that error and print out all the relevant variables that exist at the time the error occurs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but the `a:` assignment can be the result of a function or even just a block of JS code which returns some value. So you can freely use try/catch or anything else for that matter.

```
a: {
  try {
    return ((n === -1) || (n - p > 7) || (index >= t)) ? "" : b[p+index].c;
  } 
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return "FUBAR";
  }
}
```

*ADDED*: The `return` keywords are actually optional here, works just as well w/out them.

Also to point out:

`a: ((n === -1) || (n - p > 7) || (index >= t)) ? "" : b[p+index].c;`

is same as:

`a: { ((n === -1) || (n - p > 7) || (index >= t)) ? "" : b[p+index].c; }`

The curly braces are simply optional for single-line expressions.